# Ascorbic Acid, Calcium Propionate - Differences?

Tags: baking, bread, food-preservation, mold

We use ascorbic acid to help keep our breads from molding over but we have now the option to use calcium propionate. I can't find much online to help distinguish the pros and cons of each of these compared to one another.

Does anyone have any insight on which would be better used for bread making?

Answer (score 2):

As you're asking for "better", well:

- better would be to use *no preservatives* and combat mould contamination in your bakery by using other means like an improved sanitary process.

However, as you're also asking for pros and cons in a bakery environment as well, chemically speaking [L-Ascorbic Acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascorbic_acid) is... well... an acid, so the advantage of [Calcium Porpanoate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_propanoate) is that it allows bread to be stored for the same time as with using L-Ascorbic Acid but without the faintly acidic taste that goes with an acid and that it combats mould better than L-Ascorbic Acid.